# How to mock Azure KeyVaultKey C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm currently trying to unit test some Azure Functions and the service requires to get a KeyVaultKey from Azure Key Vault, key that will be used to encrypt some data. I would like to setup a mock of the operation below and return an own custom KeyVaultKey. Unfortunately, I'm unaware of how to create an instance of a functional KeyVaultKey.

```
 KeyVaultKey key = await KeyClient.GetKeyAsync(KeyVaultEncryptionKey).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My mock:

```
var keyClient = new Mock<KeyClient>();
            var azureResponse = new Mock<Response>();
            Response<KeyVaultKey> response = Response.FromValue(GetKey(), azureResponse.Object);
            keyClient.Setup(c => c.GetKeyAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(response));

    private KeyVaultKey GetKey()
    {
        var generatedKey = RSA.Create();
        var keyProperties = new KeyProperties("key");


        var webKey = new Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.JsonWebKey(generatedKey, includePrivateParameters: true);
        var keyVault = KeyModelFactory.KeyVaultKey(keyProperties, webKey);
        return keyVault;
    }
```

Could anyone show me where is my mistake and show me how to properly mock a KeyVaultKey?

Comment: @404 the azure team invested heavily in new SDKs that make it easier to mock services. Sure you could wrap everything in an interface just for the very rare case you want to switch out implementations but I don't think that is an issue for now

Comment: @moon, what exactly is going wrong? At a glance there is nothing wrong with your code and you are doing te right thing. What exactly is it you are trying to bring under test?

Comment: The code breaks because the value of the ID of the KeyVaultKey created is null but I can't find on my own how to set it. I'm probably just creating it wrongly/the method getKey() is not properly coded. The function that I'm trying to test looks for a KeyVaultKey in my KeyVault storage (getKeyAsync), which is then used to encrypt strings.

Comment: Try `KeyProperties(new Uri("https://unit-test.vault.azure.net/keys/unit-test-key"));`

Comment: For those interested, as I didn't want to connect to any online resource, I ended up mocking the whole encryption method and not only GetKeyAsync: 
```var asymetricVault = new Mock<IASymetricVaultCrytograpfy>();
asymetricVault.Setup(x => x.EncryptStringAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync((string input, string keyVaultName) => { return CryptographyMock.Encryption(input); }); 
``` Being CryptographyMock a simple static class containing an encryptyion and decryption method

Comment: So in order to mock the GetKeyAsync method you ended up mocking the encryption/decryption methods?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of test you need to run too, but in case it is an option to spin up a Docker container to provide a test double for Key Vault you could simply get a real key from the container instead of focusing on mocking the key.

If this option could make sense for your project, you could give Lowkey Vault a try: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault

It comes with a .Net POC too: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault-example-dotnet